# How to create shortcode for auto login after registration

Tags: shortcode, actions, user-registration

I've a code for auto-login after registration which is:

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    $request = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    wp_redirect($request);
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

what I need is to create a shortcode to control the time of redirect, I don't want it to redirect after
`$userID = wp_insert_user( $userDataArr );`

I want the redirect to happen after adding some code for extra fields
like so `update_user_meta( $userID, $fieldsArr[$fieldN], $value);`

I was thinking that I can do so by butting the ADD_ACTION code inside shortcode funtion

```
function my_login_shortcode(){
    add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
}
add_shortcode('mogincode','my_login_shortcode');
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: redirection has to happen before any content is sent to the browser, inside a shortcode is too late.

Comment: @Milo Thank you for that explanation, so How can I fix that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Because I was trying to make the redirect happen using shortcode in the registration and I didn't get the answer which can delay the redirect until I add custom textarea fields date to user profile page

- before this step `$userID = wp_insert_user( $userDataArr )` , I have no user ID yet, so I can't do update for unknown user id
- after it the redirect happens before I reach `update_user_meta( $userID, $fieldsArr[$fieldN], $value);` code, so I'm loosing the date which coming from $_POST[$fieldN], even I have user id

what I've done was setcookie for the data coming form $_POST[$fieldN] before the redirect, like so:

```
setcookie($fieldN, $value, time()+3600*24,'/','.MYSITE.com');
$userID = wp_insert_user( $userDataArr );
```

and I'm checking if cookie exist at the top of page, and handle it (caching and when I finish I delete that cookie by setting its time to minus time `-`, php normal way)

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $userID = $current_user->ID;
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$fieldN])){   
        update_user_meta( $userID, $fieldN, $_COOKIE[$fieldN]);
        setcookie($fieldN, '', time()-3600*24,'/',$homecookieURL);
    }
}
```

now the visitors can register and in the same time adding extra date for custom profile textarea fields.

I fix my problem, so I decided to share this, may someone has better solution or may I help someone need similar one :)